# Redirect http requests to apache

Tags: http, redirect, portforwarding

I want to redirect all `Http requests` in my own network to an `apache-server`.
I have an `airrouter` and tried to do this with `port-forwarding`.
My apache has the IP `192.168.1.11` and my Router `192.168.1.1`.

The portforwarding is like that

`private IP` `private Port` `Typ` `Source IP` `Public IP` `Public Port`
192.168.1.11  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_TCP _ 0.0.0.0/0___ 0.0.0.0/0 ***_*_**_80

But the router dont redirect me.
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

- Ensure that your port forwarding rule is enabled.
- Edit rule by adding a private port to local machine port
- Check your local machine's firewall settings. Check if allow traffic to specific port/service.